# SQL 2008 R2 Mirroring Issue

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

Windows 2008 R2 with SQL 2008 R2 - Using Mirroring of a Database across the WAN in a HA setup with one witness.

One issue I am having is during a failure (ever so often) the system fails over or tries, but leaves both databases in a Restoring State. My guess is the failover issue happens when there is a WAN bouncing and the systems get confused. The usual fix is to reboot the sql servers.

Has anyone seen this type of failure? While this does not happen often it does causes an issue and concern with HA not being trusted fully.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your setup?  A small diagram with the two sites and where each server is would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are there multiple data centers involved? Where is the witness located in relation to the principal and mirror when this occurs?

If the principal loses connectivity to the witness and mirror, then it will shutdown as well.

If the WAN is bouncing as you suggest, perhaps the principal fails over to the mirror, thus becoming the principal.

Then, if the WAN goes down a second time, the new principal just lost connectivity to both the witness and the mirror and then goes offline itself.